# Почему бот discord py работает как 1 на разных серверах

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

У меня есть discord py бот. Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы его можно было добавить на 2 разных сервера и он работал асинхронно?
(Сейчас он при команде с первого сервера начинает играть музыку в другом)
Вот часть кода:

```
class MyBot(commands.Cog):
def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
    self.bot = bot
    self.connect = None
    self.voice_channel = None

@commands.command()
async def join(self, ctx):
    self.voice_channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name=ctx.message.author.voice.channel.name)
    if not self.connect:
        self.connect = await self.voice_channel.connect()

@commands.command()
async def leave(self, ctx):
    if self.connect:
        await self.connect.disconnect()
        del self.connect
```

Comment: Не вижу вашего кода

Comment: Пока вы не приложите код к вашему вопросу, вам на вряд ли смогут чем-то помочь. Могу лишь предположить, что проблема в том, что вы в каких-то частях кода работаете с объектом конкретного сервера, получаете его не из контекста, а, например, по `id`.

Comment: @denisnumb Я прикрепил часть кода. Всё остальное примерно в таком же формате. Всю информацию я беру из контекста. Буду рад любой помощи

Comment: так у вас объект текущего канала `self.voice_channel = None` так или иначе привязан к одному серверу. Когда вы вызываете команду со второго серва, он смотрит, и видит что голосовой канал уже есть (но этот канал с первого сервера). Как вариант, можете создать словарь и записать объекты голосовых каналов туда, и обращаться к ним через ключ-id сервера: `voice_channels = {int_id_сервера: None}`. Ну и динамически добавлять туда каналы, при вызове команды с нового сервера

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил, но это пол беды. Бот почему-то реагирует на команды с другого сервера.  @denisnumb

Comment: а разве не должен?

Comment: По идее нет. На каждом сервере бот должен отвечать по своему. Т.е. если на первом сервере включили песню, она не должна мешать и повторятся на втором. Как пример: боты, которых просто добавляешь на сервер и пользуешься(ProBot, Tempo и т.д). Я бы хотел так же. Есть же, наверное, способ сделать так же или я ошибаюсь? @denisnumb

Comment: Я не делал мультисерверных ботов, поэтому не знаю максимально правильной реализации этого. Лично мне на ум приходит использование словаря, в котором с ключами в виде `id` серверов, на которых сидит бот, можно добавить другие словари, содержащие различные переменные для конкретного сервера (`voice_channel`, `очередь` и другие)

Comment: Спасибо за идею. Попробую ей реализовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спустя некоторое время я догадался до такой структуры:

При инициализации бота я добавляю все его сервера в словарь {сервер: объект бота, который будет обрабатывать команду}. Получилось как-то так:

```
self.guilds: Dict[discord.Guild, GuildThread.GuildThread] = {}
```

```
for guild in self.bot.guilds:
    self.guilds[guild] = GuildThread.GuildThread(self.bot, guild)
```

```
async def join(self, ctx: commands.Context) -> None:
    await self.guilds[ctx.guild].join(ctx)
```

Не знаю правильно ли я сделал, но этот способ выглядит очень логично и удобно.

Answer (score 0):

Тебе надо делать бд для всех серверов. Изучи питон и базы данных.
[Python, введение в БД](https://habr.com/ru/post/481084/)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]